# loads of spaces when echoing php string after using str_replace

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have php code removing the file type from the end of it using the code bellow

```
$atrib = str_replace('.m3u', '', $atrib); // strip off the playlist extension
```

Every time I seem to use it there is loads of eather blank spaces or white spaces showing after it when I echo it out there is ruffly about 5 blank spaces after it

Before I use `str_replace` the url looks like so:

`"http://example.com/playlist/movie1.m3u"`

After I use `str_replace` when I echo out my string it now looks like this where you see ###### it is just a blank space

`"http://example.com/playlist/movie1########"`

as you can see there is a big space after movie one before it reaches "

Comment: What returns `echo '#' . $atrib . '#';` ?

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($atrib);`

Comment: What version of PHP? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/807fc5b6dceb5688c180a7b67ca96278bee232f7 seems to be working.

Comment: wen i use var_dump this is shown string(3) "movie1"

and wen i do echo '#' . $atrib . '#'; this is shown #movie1#

note that wen i remove the str_replace function the url is echoed out with out the spaces :/

Comment: You need show output of `var_dump($atrib);` before `str_replace` call.

Comment: if i do var dump before str is called all i get is string(3) "movie1.m3u"

Comment: How can `"movie1.m3u"` be `string(3)` when there are more than 3 characters.

Comment: i dont know lol that waht i get tho :/ i have been googling for this all day and nothing

@nickb some people like me have mental helth problems such as dislexia if you dont like it dont read simple spelling reading and wrighting is hard for me

Comment: Like @anubhava said, need to `var_dump` because possibly, there's spaces already attached. However try just [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) `$atrib = rtrim(str_replace('.m3u', '', $atrib));` [see example](https://eval.in/178206)

Comment: @Jonny5 don't you think that dot should be escaped like `\.m3u`

Comment: @Jonny5 oh sorry confused with `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with capturing groups.

```
^(.*)(\..*)$
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ1rH5/5) and tested it at [php.fnlist.com](http://php.fnlist.com/regexp/preg_replace)

sample code: (code taken from above mentioned site)

```
$re = "/^(.*)(\\..*)$/";
$str = "http://example.com/playlist/movie1.m3u";
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: this would be ok but the end of the url changes every time the page is loaded movie1 ca turn into movie2 ,movie10 and more

Comment: yes it will work for each url. I haven't used any movie in my regex pattern `^(.*)(\..*)$` It's a simply split into 2 groups based on last dot.